# Grease Pencil - glow transparency

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm having trouble achieving a simple glow effect in GP. Instead of solid color fading out into transparency, I'm getting solid color fading into world background color. Would be grateful for any help.[image]
blender file: [test.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YjIFIB49lSst97XVFtsjsPqP7IFP3dMJ/view?usp=sharing)

edit: added blender file

Comment: try unchecking alpha mode.  maybe increasing the samples?

Comment: @Millard unfortunately, that didn't help :(

Comment: weird, I'm not sure what's going on, hope someone can help you.